# How to prove that an isometry of a plane which is the product of a translation and rotation is a rotation about a point in the plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

In Artin's Algebra, he proves this by choosing appropriate coordinates for the plane so that the formula for the isometry $m = t_ap_\theta$ can be reduced to $m'=p_\theta$. This is of course intuitively right, but I am still having a hard time understanding why this is true. We do not even have a formal definition for rotation in this book, how do I even prove that something is a rotation?

Comment: you may try to come up with a geometric construction, first step try to find which point is fixed under $m = t_ap_\theta$

Comment: How you define a rotation depends on how you define the plane.I recommend the small book Foundations Of Geometry by David Hilbert. And for elementary geometry in general, Introduction To Geometry by Donald Coxeter is superb. Also a smaller book by Coxeter : Geometry Re-Visited.

Comment: Is it necessary to dive into Euclidean geometry? I mean most universities nowadays do not even have an elementary course for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the isometry $F$ is a rotation about a point $p$ followed by a translation $t_a,$ choose the origin to be $p.$  Then $$F(x)=a+M_b(x)$$ where $M_b$ is a rotation thru angle $b$ about $p.$ Now a rotation thru angle $b$ about a point $q$ is $$G(x)=q+M_b(x-q).$$ If there exist $q$ such that $$a=q-M_bq$$ then we have $$F=G.$$  (1). If $t_a$ is the identity function then with respect to the origin $p,$ we have $a=0=p$ and we  choose $q=p.$...(2). If $t_a$ is not the identity and $M_b$ is also not the identity $I,$ then $\cos b \ne 1$ and we choose $$q=(2-2\cos b)^{-1}(I-M_{-b}) a.$$ Huh?  $(I-M_{-b})(I-M_b)a=(2-[M_b+M_{-b}])a.$ Draw a diagram to compute that $$(M_b+M_{-b})a=(2\cos b)a.$$ The point is that if $\cos b\ne 1$ then the function $(I-M_b)$ has an inverse, and we choose $q=(I-M_b)^{-1}a.$.....(3).Special case. If $t_a\ne I$ and $M_b=I,$ we have $F(x)=a+x$,  but for any rotation $H(x)=q+M_c(x-q)$ ,then regardless of $q$ and $c,$ we have  $F(q)=q+a\ne q=H(x).$ So the statement should be amended, as we generally regard the identity to be a rotation $M_0$ thru angle $0$.

Comment: My question is how do you prove that a linear operator is rotation? I haven't encountered a rigorous definition of rotation yet, so I am having a really hard time understanding Artin's proof.

Comment: In co-ordinates a rotation about the origin,  thru angle T,  sends the 2-entry column vector v ,whose entries are x and y,... to Mv .... where M is a 2x2 matrix whose first row entries  are (cos T) and (-sin T) and whose second row  entries are (sin T) and (cos T)....( I haven't found out how to format  matrices .)

Comment: Then what's the rotation about a point other than the origin?

Comment: f(v)=p+M(v-p) for fixed vector p,and rotation M about the origin, is rotation about p.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one more question. Is it necessary to dive into Euclidean geometry?

Comment: The geometry is not really necessary. You can use the basics of matrix  theory to confirm that the matrix $I-M_b$ has an inverse when $M_b$ represents a rotation thru angle $b$ when $M_b\ne I$.